# Spring Boot - Embedded tomcat startup message

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

When i start my spring boot application using eclipse , I see the below text after the embedded tomcat is started :

```
s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
```

However when I start using command prompt using the command  **java -jar "build\libs\newservice-0.1.0.jar"** , i don't see the above listed line. I see one similar to below -

> Starting application on patqpl-6GTRF with PID 2212 (started by vserri
>   in C:\workspace\newservice) Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2de40c40:
>   startup date [Mon Nov 02 18:34:47 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
>   Started application in 0.28 seconds (JVM running for 30.28) Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@671ec3a3:
>   startup date [Mon Nov 02 18:34:47 EST 2015]; parent:
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2de40c40
>   JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for
>   autowiring Started application in 0.502 seconds (JVM running for
>   30.484)

Is there a reason why "java -jar "build\libs\newservice-0.1.0.jar" is not displayed while starting from command prompt?

Comment: Perhaps you use different application properties when running from jar or your eclipse project has different launch parameters ? We can only guess ...

Comment: Thanks Marged , it seems to be the same , but will verify again